# Navbar changing its position after applying position: fixed value to it

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-position

The code before applying position: fixed value

```
#nav {
  top: 0%;
  margin-left: -300px; 
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

And the screenshot of website
[image]

The code after applying position: fixed to it

```
#nav {
  top: 0%;
  margin-left: -300px; 
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: fixed;
}
```

And now the website [image: oof]

My HTML:

```html
<nav id= "nav" class="w3-center w3-animate-top">
 <ul>
   <li> <a href="#"> Home </a></li>
   <li> <a href="#"> Games </a></li>
   <li> <a href="#"> Videos </a></li>
   <li> <a href="#"> Portfolio </a></li>
   <li> <a href="#"> Contacc </a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
</nav>
```

Comment: `fixed` is relative to the viewport (with some exceptions). Please include your HTML as well. CSS is useless without your HTML.

Comment: I do have viewport tag in my html file @disinfor

Comment: That doesn't help at all. Post your HTML for your `#nav` menu. Edit your question and use the `<>` snippet feature.

Comment: @disinfor done.

Comment: Why're you applying a negative margin in pixel? Are you targeting a specific device? Also if you're using fixed position, you've to set width manually if you want it to consume entire available width

Comment: Is there any other way to keep nav on top without using fixed position @Sagar V

Comment: you can use fixed position. But use % instead of px. Try `width: 100%; top: 0px; left: 0px;`

Comment: @SagarV uhh this is happening after i put your code

Comment: [Image](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/743872699281047682/775643900727263232/unknown.png)

Comment: @ImagineGamingPlay what are you trying to achieve? items on center?

Answer (score 0):

please remove **-300px** and try, it will bring the content to center. If that is all what you were asking, otherwise please provide the other code as it seems that navbar design css is not from w3 css.